# Is it possible to use CEA RUN for cold gas thruster?

Tags: rocket

I am trying to observe nozzle design for a cold gas nitrogen system. It you can do reactants in the CEA RUN program, but I am trying to observe if I just want the pressure of a cold gas system as the propellant.